# Making stylized and animated HTML5 button an entirely clickable link

Tags: html, css, button

I have made a button using  which must include a picture and text. Here is an example of what I have at the moment

https://jsfiddle.net/9c9dnot9/

```
<button id="CLPButton" class="DeptButton">
    <span>
        <table style="width:120%">
        <tr>
            <th><img src="http://i.imgur.com/vjrbizL.png"></th>
            <th>Clinical Lab <br> Platforms</th> 
        </tr>
        </table>
    </span>
</button>
```

The reason I have it set up as a table is to properly adjust the alignment and formatting of the image and text within the button.

I can wrap the image and the text in  tags to href to the page I want to link to.... but then you have to click the picture or the text. I want the entire button to be clickable and redirect to the URL.

I have tried every tip and trick I could find on numerous forums but can't seem to get it to work. Things either outright fail or completely screw up the formatting.

The purpose of this is to have a series of buttons for a SharePoint site which link to certain corporate departments.

I am somewhat new at coding in general so the more explanation the better! Thank you

Comment: IM not sure I see any issue. The entire button is clickable for me. If the text is a child of the image container, than all you need to do is attach the <a> tag to the image as the image covers the entire button background. The text being a child will bubble the click event to the image, so it dont matter where you click - as long as it is within the button boundary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buttons are not intended to be links. The purpose of a button is to interact with HTML forms (e.g. submitting form data).

If you want to have something that looks like a button and behaves like a link, then I would recommend creating a link and styling it with CSS to look like a button.

In your fiddle, you can actually just change your `<button>` markup to `<a>` and it should all work fine.

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9c9dnot9/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the entire button in an `a` tag and add the `display: block` property in order to set its height depending on its content. Then, instead of setting the width on the button, set it on the link and add `width: 100%` to the button instead, so your link won't take the full width of its container and your button will be more maintenable because you won't have to set the width of the link and the button if you decide to change !

Here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/d5tcamok/2/